# Editing JSFiddle answers into Code Snippet Answers

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I edited this answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26058615/revisions)), which originally included a JSFiddle link. I changed it to instead be a Code Snippet.

My reasoning was that JSFiddle is an outside source (That one day could change/be removed) and the answer would be better suited to a Code Snippet as it wasn't a lot of code and was easier to see the CSS changes on the same page as the CSS problem.

Are these sorts of edits encouraged/discouraged or does it really not matter at this point? I'd like to know so in future I can make similar edits or avoid it.

As I've done the answer, should I also change the Question to include a code snippet? What about the other answers that weren't marked as 'Correct'?

Comment: No, unless you're also making other major edits to the question/answer.